# Invalid object name 'dbo.Infoes' when retrieving data from DB using EF

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqlexception

I'm really a beginner to MVC. I've made view that simply retrieves data from a table named `Info` using this code

Controller :

```
namespace FP.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IRetrieveData repo;
        public HomeController(IRetrieveData repoParam)
        {
            repo = repoParam;
        }
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            Info model = repo.Info.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

And the view :

```
<div id="follow">
    <a href="http://@Model.Facebook.Substring(Model.Facebook.IndexOf("http://")+1,Model.Facebook.Length)"><img src="img/temp.png" alt="facebook"/></a>
    <a href="http://@Model.Twitter.Substring(Model.Twitter.IndexOf("http://")+1,Model.Twitter.Length)"><img src="img/temp.png" alt="twitter"/></a>
    <a href="mailto://@Model.Email"><img src="img/temp.png" alt="email"/></a>
</div>
```

But i always get this exception right in the line :

```
Info model = repo.Info.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

The exception is :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Invalid object name 'dbo.Infoes'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object
>   name 'dbo.Infoes'.

**I have no idea where's the problem so i'll put the related parts of the project.**

---

The connection string inside the root `Web.config`:

```
 <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="EFDbContext" providerName="system.data.sqlclient" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=photography;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

EFDbContext class :

```
namespace FP.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Gallery> Gallery { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SessionImages> SessionImages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sessions> Sessions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Admins> Admins { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Info> Info { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Offers> Offers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EFDbRetrieve class :

```
namespace FP.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFDbRetrieve : IRetrieveData
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IQueryable<Admins> Admins
        {
            get { return context.Admins; }
        }

        public IQueryable<Gallery> Gallery
        {
            get { return context.Gallery; }
        }

        public IQueryable<SessionImages> SessionImages
        {
            get { return context.SessionImages; }
        }

        public IQueryable<Sessions> Sessions
        {
            get { return context.Sessions; }
        }

        public IQueryable<Offers> Offers
        {
            get { return context.Offers; }
        }

        public IQueryable<Info> Info
        {
            get { return context.Info; }
        }
    }
}
```

IRetrieveData interface :

```
namespace FP.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IRetrieveData : IAdmins, IGallery, ISessionImages, ISessions, IOffers, IInfo
    {
    }
}
```

Which inherits from IInfo interface :

```
namespace FP.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IInfo
    {
        IQueryable<Info> Info { get; }
    }
}
```

I'd be very grateful if someone helped me out in this, i'm getting frustrated.

Comment: That's a mapping error (probably due to pluralization of table names created from entity classes), yet you haven't included your table mappings :)

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor Could you provide me with a tutorial or a video that explains that mapping thing ? Thanks a lot

Comment: [Here's a tutorial with a video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620), mappings included. If you want to auto-map, use the solution from the answer.

Comment: I want 3 hours of my life back...  Thanks Patryk and lopezbertoni (below). I could not apply the global solution of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); so instead I did modelBuilder.Entity<UserEmailAddress>().ToTable("UserEmailAddress"); and that solidified the naming convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like they suggested, the problem is that the table names are getting pluralized (Info maps to a table called Infoes). You can check the table names in SQL. To disable this, add:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

to the EFDbContext class.

Hope this helps